# Prevent mysql query from giving multiple rows of same id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates

At first, it's a bit complicated to create an SQL fiddle with the problem because the data amount is huge. By this I try to drop an screenshot with the result I have.

The problem seems to be small, my query runs perfectly but because different images are linked to different locations in the same city (or cities in range of the distance) I get back two times or more the same image at this time. Because this query is running on 'city' niveau, I just need to get back one image as I need the first one out of the results (supposed to be the closest one to my lan/lon).

The query:

```
SELECT c.slug
    ,l.location_id
    ,fl.flyer_id
    ,f.salt
    ,f.NAME
    ,f.online
    ,f.cover
    ,fc.cat_id
    ,ca.NAME AS cat_name
    ,lan
    ,lon
    ,(6371 * acos(cos(radians(1.5000759112888)) * cos(radians(lan)) * cos(radians(lon) - radians(2.6118285879120)) + sin(radians(1.5000759112888)) * sin(radians(lan)))) AS distance
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN locations l
    ON c.slug = l.city_slug
INNER JOIN flyers_locations fl
    ON l.location_id = fl.location_id
INNER JOIN flyers_categories fc
    ON fl.flyer_id = fc.flyer_id
INNER JOIN categories ca
    ON fc.cat_id = ca.id
INNER JOIN flyers f
    ON fl.flyer_id = f.id
HAVING distance < 25
    AND l.location_id != ''
    AND fc.cat_id = '41'
    AND f.online = '1'
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

The result

[image]

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need to use the location_id field ? if no, try to take it off from your select and use distinct. If yes, then you could use a group function and get the lower or higher location_id using min or max(location_id) and group by other fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t want an image to appear twice you could try using `distinct` in front of the column name.

But if you realy only want to fetch the first one why not just set the limit to 1? This way you would only get the first (closest) row.

Comment: Sorry, I don't just want to fetch one result. There are many more rows but just didn't link a categorie to them at the moment, so they don't appear. I've tried to use distinct right after SELECT but this doesn't make any changes to the result.

Comment: if you put it after SELECT ist affects the slug. Put it infront of the column for the image. If it´s the cover column write `[...],DISTINCT f.cover,[...]` in the SELECT

Comment: f.id, f.salt, f.name, f.online, DISTINCT f.cover, ., throws me "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct f.cover,                     lan, lon, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(52.3777' at line 5 0.072 sec" I will try to create a sqlfiddle

Comment: Tried it my self with a simplified sample, seems like you can´t use DISTINCT that way. Is it possible that two rows with same image have different distances?

Comment: You are faster as me! Yes, this is possible. There is only one image (flyer cover) in the database as this one can be connected to more than just 1 location. I've added a screenshot with output of the distance included

Comment: And if the distances is dirfferent should only the first be returned too or both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91846/discussion-between-user5400659-and-freshtea).